# Is a state in the GHZ entanglement class iff it's true 3-partite entangled and at least one of its reduced states is mixed?

Tags: entanglement

Consider 3-qubit state. In [W. Dür et al. (2000)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005115), it is stated that a 3-qubit state can be 3-partite entangled in 2 different ways. We call it entanglement classes. GHZ state is a representative of one class, let us call it GHZ-like class, while the W state is a representative of the second class (W-like class).

Did I understand it correctly that the state belongs to the GHZ-like class if and only if it is true 3-partite entangled and at least one of its reduced density matrices is mixed?